# Integrating react-helmet as dynamic meta tag in react js appliction

Tags: reactjs, meta-tags

I am trying to implement [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet)  as a dynamic meta tag in our application, which uses server side rendering. I am little confused about it's setup ([react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet)), it's working but breaking on first page load. The second time I reload the page the tag displayed however. I am also getting errors in the browser console. Please can someone suggest what to do? Please see my code below,

I access the route http://localhost:8081/about

Layout.jsx

```
var React = require('react');
var Helmet = require('react-helmet');

var Layout = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'Layout',
    render: function() {
        "use strict";
        let head = Helmet.rewind();
        return (
            <html>
                <head>
                  <link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/application.css' />
                  {head.title.toComponent()}
                  {head.meta.toComponent()}
                  {head.link.toComponent()}
                </head>
                <body >
                    {this.props.children}

                </body>
            </html>
        );
    }
});

module.exports= Layout;
```

About.jsx

```
var React = require('react');
var Helmet = require('react-helmet');

module.exports = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'About',
    render: function() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Helmet
              title="About Title"
              meta={[
                  {"name": "about description", "content": "about Helmet application"}
              ]}
            />
            <p>
                Current: <strong>About</strong>
            </p>
          </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Please find the attachments,
[image]
[image]

Please suggest what to do, reply if any other information needed.

Comment: I've tried your code, it seams working fine. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFagi.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFagi.png)